# OpenApi Codegen "Failed to get the schema name:"

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-codegen, openapi-generator, codegen

i use OpenAPI Generator to generate client on based my swagger.yaml
i have this part of code:

```
...
    responses:
        '400':
           $ref: "#/errors/400"
...
errors:
  '400':
    description: invalid request
    content:
      application/json:
        schema:
          $ref: "#/components/schemas/ErrResp"

...
components:
   schemas:
      ErrResp:
        type: object
        properties:
          error_code:
            $ref: "#/components/schemas/ErrCode"
          error_msg:
            type: string
      ErrCode:
         type: integer
         description: |
           2 - invalid request

...
```

Generation is performed using this command:

```
openapi-generator generate -i myAPI.yaml -g typescript-fetch -o ./myAPI"
```

and have warning:

```
[main] WARN  o.o.codegen.utils.ModelUtils - Failed to get the schema name: #/errors/400
```

At the same time, the check for editor.swagger.io passes without errors and warnings - the file is described correctly. I temporarily found the following solution on how to avoid this warning, but I want to find out why it occurs, and I would like to keep the current structure in order to avoid redundancy.

The solution is:
Instead

```
responses:
   '400':
      $ref: "#/errors/400"
```

the following is used, in which case there are no warnings:

```
responses:
     '400':
        description: invalid request
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: "#/components/schemas/ErrResp"
```

Answer (score -1):

Looking at the [spec](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.3.md#oasObject) i think `errors` is not allowed at the top level.

It allows extensions, so `x-errors` might work.